# Specifying platform options for Visual studio solution to run cmd in batch

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am running a Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio 2015 from a batch script. I want it to run in release mode (want an APK file created in release mode) and using following code to do so.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\devenv.com" %SamplesSolutionPath% /run "Release|x86"
```

But it is running in debug mode and generating APK in debug mode.

Is there a way to insist to run the solution in release mode?

Comment: `/Build  "Release|x86" /Run`?

Comment: @JosefZ thanks for your response. but its not even building the solution.with above syntax.